# Load a R library in shell script

Tags: r, shell, unix

I want to go in to R and load a library in shell script to do some analysis but i am getting error like this

```
syntax error near unexpected token `GenomicRanges'
```

This is my shell script(i have loaded R module in bash_profile)

```
#$ -S /bin/bash

for sample in *.txt; do
       R # Enter R
       library(GenomicRanges) # Load library
       ## 
       do some analysis later
       ##
done
```

Is there a way i can load a R library with in shell script and run some analysis?

Comment: This looks really inefficient. You know that you can loop in R?

Comment: In terminal, type R and go through the script line by line until you come up with an error. See `?list.files` and `sapply` or `lapply` on how to go through the files "in a loop". Answers involving these commands are very common on SO's `r` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use heredoc notation (`<<`):

```
for sample in *.txt; do

R --no-save<<EOF
library(GenomicRanges)
read.table(file = "$sample", ...)
# some R code ...
....
EOF

done
```

Note that inside the script you can refer to other shell variables, e.g. `$sample`. Be careful to escape all occurences of `$` that need to be in the R code using backslash: `\$`.

Comment: I am getting error like this a.sh: line 14: warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
a.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file @Tomas

Comment: i got it i need to have <<-EOF @Tomas

Comment: @abh Oh sorry - the EOF must be at the very beginning of line - so maybe remove the indentation completely. Updated my answer.